# Modules and general linear group of order $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, modules

> Let $R$ be a Principal Ideal Domain. Let $M=\oplus_{i=1}^n R$ be a
> free module of rank $n$. Let $v=(a_{1},a_{2},...a_{n})\in M$ be such
> that ideal generated by $a_{1},a_{2},...a_{n}$ is $R$.
>
> Show that:
>
> $(a)$ $M/Rv$ is a free $R$ module,
>  $(b)$ There is a invetible
> matrix $A\in GL_{n}(R)$ whose first row is $v$.

Can anyone explain to me, what the question is trying to ask? and what it seeks to establish?

Moreover, please provide me a rough idea for the proof.

Comment: sorry, i misread the statement.... But in (b) it is "invertible", not "singular".

Comment: @GreginGre But why do you think it is "*invertible and not singular*"?

Comment: because $GL_n(R)$ is the notation for the group of invertible matrices...and because otherwise, it does not make sense: you could always take the first row to be  $v$ and fill in the other rows with zeroes.

Comment: @GreginGre Is it correct now? I have edited it

Comment: yes, now it is.

Comment: @BillDubuque Can you check this?